# vagrant up intermittent error "SSH responded with a non-zero exit status" or boot timeout error

Tags: vagrant

Most of the time whenever I run `vagrant up` it hangs up somewhere then eventually after a couple of minutes the following shows. This is a completely newly installed vagrant, VirtualBox, Homestead so I'm wondering what's wrong because these are all unmodified.

```
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

mv -f '/tmp/vagrant-network-entry-1602866071' '/etc/netplan/50-vagrant.yaml'
chown root:root '/etc/netplan/50-vagrant.yaml'
chmod 0644 '/etc/netplan/50-vagrant.yaml'
netplan apply

Stdout from the command:



Stderr from the command:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/sbin/netplan", line 23, in <module>
    netplan.main()
  File "/usr/share/netplan/netplan/cli/core.py", line 50, in main
    self.run_command()
  File "/usr/share/netplan/netplan/cli/utils.py", line 186, in run_command
    self.func()
  File "/usr/share/netplan/netplan/cli/commands/apply.py", line 46, in run
    self.run_command()
  File "/usr/share/netplan/netplan/cli/utils.py", line 186, in run_command
    self.func()
  File "/usr/share/netplan/netplan/cli/commands/apply.py", line 174, in command_apply
    subprocess.check_call(['udevadm', 'settle'])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 311, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['udevadm', 'settle']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
 INFO interface: Machine: error-exit ["Vagrant::Errors::VagrantError", "The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.\nVagrant assumes that this means the command failed!\n\nmv -f '/tmp/vagrant-network-entry-1602866071' '/etc/netplan/50-vagrant.yaml'\nchown root:root '/etc/netplan/50-vagrant.yaml'\nchmod 0644 '/etc/netplan/50-vagrant.yaml'\nnetplan apply\n\nStdout from the command:\n\n\n\nStderr from the command:\n\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/usr/sbin/netplan\", line 23, in <module>\n    netplan.main()\n  File \"/usr/share/netplan/netplan/cli/core.py\", line 50, in main\n    self.run_command()\n  File \"/usr/share/netplan/netplan/cli/utils.py\", line 186, in run_command\n    self.func()\n  File \"/usr/share/netplan/netplan/cli/commands/apply.py\", line 46, in run\n    self.run_command()\n  File \"/usr/share/netplan/netplan/cli/utils.py\", line 186, in run_command\n    self.func()\n  File \"/usr/share/netplan/netplan/cli/commands/apply.py\", line 174, in command_apply\n    subprocess.check_call(['udevadm', 'settle'])\n  File \"/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py\", line 311, in check_call\n    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)\nsubprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['udevadm', 'settle']' returned non-zero exit status 1.\n"]
```

What most fascinates me because sometimes everything just works well without error but that just like 6 or more runs because it happens.

Here are my versions I'm using:

```
Windows 10 Pro
vagrant_2.2.10_x86_64.msi
VirtualBox-6.1.14-140239-Win.exe
```

Also, sometimes when I `vagrant halt` then run `vagrant up` again, this will show:

```
==> homestead: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    homestead: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    homestead: SSH username: vagrant
    homestead: SSH auth method: private key
Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.

If you look above, you should be able to see the error(s) that
Vagrant had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errors
are usually good hints as to what may be wrong.

If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly
working and you're able to connect to the machine. It is a common
problem that networking isn't setup properly in these boxes.
Verify that authentication configurations are also setup properly,
as well.

If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increase
the timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.
```

So the error isn't consistent.

Comment: There might be an error in /var/log/syslog in the box. Could you post it?